# Instagram Like Follow Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I am trying to write a query that would return a list of followings but there are some requirements like it is on Instagram.

Scenario:

**A user 'A' browses through user 'B' account and views a list of users the user 'B' follows**

1. If 'B' follows 'A' then the account of 'A' should top the returned list.
2. If 'B' and 'A' has common followings ie (users they both follow), then that should be next in line in the returned list after item no 1.
3. Then other users from 'B' followings.

What I have done:

```
    //the followings of who is requesting
        var requestingUserFollowing = repository_.ChannelMemberReadOnly()
            .Where(c => c.MemberUserId == requestingUserId.Value)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated);

        //the followings of the user requested
        var requestedUserFollowing = repository_.ChannelMemberReadOnly()
            .Where(c => c.MemberUserId == request.RequestedUserId)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated);

        //users that both the requesting user and requested user are following
        var commonFollowing = requestedUserFollowing.Intersect(requestingUserFollowing);

        //followings except common following
        var remainingUsers = requestedUserFollowing.Except(commonFollowing);

      
        var count = await finalQueryResult.CountAsync();

         //final query resulting in RequestingUser Account + Common Follow + Other Follow
        var finalQueryResult = requestedUserFollowing.Union(commonFollowing).Union(remainingUsers);

        var count = await finalQueryResult.CountAsync();

        var followings = await finalQueryResult
            .Include(c => c.ChannelInfo)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.User)
            .Select(c => ConvertModelToApi.ToApi(configuration_, c.ChannelInfo.User))
            .PerPage(request.Page, request.PerPage)
            .ToListAsync();

        return new()
        {
            Total = count,
            Followings = followings
        };
```

Now this is not giving me the expected order:

1. Account of User A if applicable
2. The followings of User A if applicable
3. Other followers.

Comment: Well, you're returning `requestedUserFollowing` and ignoring the work you do with `commonFollowing`, `remainingUsers`, and `finalQueryResult`, so I don't expect it would return in the "expected" order. Perhaps you want to return `finalQueryResult`?

Comment: Okay let me do that, thanks

Comment: So I changed it, but I am not getting the order I expected.

Comment: Now you're using `Union` instead of `Concat`, and I believe `Union` doesn't need to respect the order of items. Whether things like `.Intersect`, etc. work depends on whether or not the items they're operating on override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. If they don't, then two objects that look the same to you could actually be different. Without a lot more detail, I can't possibly say why these aren't working.

Comment: The logic seems to work just fine on a basic value type such as `int`: https://rextester.com/QMNNS13994

Comment: I was thinking maybe there was something off with the queries, I didn't how it is with integer type, but since it worked well then It should be fine, somehow something is off